# Get a PHP object property that is a number

Tags: php, json, object, properties

I'm trying to get a property from JSON data decoded into a PHP object. It's just a YouTube data API request that returns a video object that has a content object liks so;

```
[content] => stdClass Object
                (
                    [5] => https://www.youtube.com/v/r4ihwfQipfo?version=3&f=videos&app=youtube_gdata
                    [1] => rtsp://v4.cache7.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQn6pSL0waGIrxMYDSANFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
                    [6] => rtsp://v6.cache3.c.youtube.com/CiILENy73wIaGQn6pSL0waGIrxMYESARFEgGUgZ2aWRlb3MM/0/0/0/video.3gp
                )
```

Doing

```
$object->content->5
```

Throws "unexpected T_DNUMBER" - which makes perfect sense. But how do I get the value of a property that is a number?

I'm sure I should know this. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Definitely one of the more annoying nuances of PHP.

Comment: [This explain it perfectly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10333016/6521116)

Answer (score 83, accepted):

This should work:

`$object->content->{'5'}`

Comment: Didn't work. Caught a `Undefined property: stdClass::$5`. Using PHP Version 5.5.7

Comment: This workflow DOES NOT WORK if the variable was an array that has been cast to an object.  A detailed explanation and examples can be found here: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/58795

Answer (score 20):

Another possibility is to use the 2nd parameter to json_decode:

```
$obj = json_decode(str, true);
```

You get an array instead of a PHP object, which you can then index as usual:

```
$obj['content'][5]
```

Answer (score 2):

JSON encode, and then decode your object passing true as the second param in the decode function.  This will return an associative array.

```
$array = json_decode(json_encode($object), true);
```

Now you can use your new array

```
echo $array['content']['5'];
```

---

Using `$object->content->{'5'}` will **not** work if the object was created by casting an array to an object.

A more detailed description can be found here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/10333200/58795