# getting php variable from an object in which one of its properties has $ sign

Tags: php, json, variables, object

so I acquired a json object from an API and json decoded it...

but then the returned object is of the following:

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => stdClass Object
        (
            [$t] => some string
        )
)
```

And as you can see there is a property with a $ sign in it

but when I do `$object->id->$t`  <--that returns error since it thinks $t is a variable

how would I go about fetching that variable with $ sign?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Get a PHP object property that is a number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606340/get-a-php-object-property-that-is-a-number) - Which is only one of the similar ones.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Encapsulate it as a single-quoted string:

```
echo $object->id->{'$t'};
```

Note that you cannot use double quotes for the same reason you cannot use `$object->id->$t`: PHP will attempt to interpolate `$t`. However, you could use double quotes if you escape the dollar sign:

```
echo $obj->id->{"\$t"};
```

You can see it working in [this simple demo](http://viper-7.com/96mrBI).

Comment: @Cole Thanks for the tip, I added that to my answer.