# How do I parse JSON like geo:point in PHP?

Tags: php, json, parsing

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to access an object property with a minus-sign?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940244/how-to-access-an-object-property-with-a-minus-sign)

I am trying to parse geo:point / geo:lat but getting nowhere fast. Here's the code I have so far

```
  $content = get_data('http://ws.audioscrobbler.com/2.0/?method=geo.getevents&location=united+kingdom&api_key=XXX&format=json&limit=10000&festivalsonly=1');
  $LFMdata = json_decode($content);
  foreach ($LFMdata->events->event as $event) {
      $venue_lat = $event->venue->location["geo:point"]["geo:lat"];
      $venue_long = $event->venue->location["geo:point"]["geo:long"];
```

The JSON will contain something like

```
"geo:point": {
     "geo:lat": "52.7352",
     "geo:long": "-1.695392"
}
```

Anyone got any idea? Seen examples in JavaScript but not PHP

Comment: What does `var_dump($LFMdata);` return?

Comment: Try `$object->{'geo:point'}->{'geo:lat}` or similar.

Comment: Are you sure you have a `location` returned as an array? Try to do `var_dump($event->venue->location)` and see what it will return

Comment: Fangel:

`object(stdClass)#6 (5) { ["geo:point"]=> object(stdClass)#7 (2) { ["geo:lat"]=> string(0) "" ["geo:long"]=> string(0) "" } ["city"]=> string(6) "London" ["country"]=> string(14) "United Kingdom" ["street"]=> string(0) "" ["postalcode"]=> string(0) "" } `

Comment: @halfer's answer is correct, or return is as an array (json_decode($data, TRUE)).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use

```
$venue_lat = $event->venue->location->{"geo:point"}->{"geo:lat"};
```

Or make it return everything like an associative array (second param of `json_decode` set to `true`):

```
 $LFMdata = json_decode($content, true);
  foreach ($LFMdata["events"]["event"] as $event) {
      $venue_lat = $event["venue"]["location"]["geo:point"]["geo:lat"];
      $venue_long = $event["venue"]["location"]["geo:point"]["geo:long"];
```