# Why is {'property'} used in PHP

Tags: php, oop

Feel free to re-title this Question because I do not know the proper name for doing this. More to the point, I have seen people using `{'property'}` when accessing a property inside an object so I set-up an example to try understand however, the property is accessible when I use it and when I don't?

```
class Example {
    public $name;
}

$e = new Example();
$e->{'name'} = 'Kdot';

echo $e->name; // output: Kdot
```

I have tried changing the scopes and accessing it through a class method but it works both ways, again.

Can someone help me understand what the meaning of using the {} delimiters are? Because from my knowledge, if you stored the parameter inside another variable, this would also work:

```
$property = 'name';
echo $e->$property; // output: Kdot
```

Comment: Many ways to do the same thing. Like in JS, you can do `window['onload']`, `window.onload` and `var name = onload; window[name]`

Comment: Is it just best-practice? @JuanMendes

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940244/how-to-access-an-object-property-with-a-minus-sign

Comment: It's not best practice to use the `{'property'}` notation, but it might be used in a specific project if they have a lot of properties that aren't valid identifiers (e.g. `{'%%property%%'}` would not be a valid identifier, but could be used as a property if it's accessed this way).

Answer (score 2):

They're mostly both just different ways to do the same thing, but with slightly different capabilities.

One difference is that if you want to concatenate inline and use that for a property name, you need the braces:

```
// example:
$property = 'foo';

echo $e->{$property . 'Suffix'}; // good, uses $e->fooSuffix
echo $e->$property . 'Suffix'    // bad, uses $e->foo and adds "Suffix" literal
```

As well as that, directly access property names need to conform to certain rules. For example [if you have a dash in your property name](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11940244/how-to-access-an-object-property-with-a-minus-sign) you need to use braces to access it.

Comment: Nice, I was struggling trying to think of an example where you needed `obj->${}`

Comment: Thanks, It was probably because I have been searching using the words prefix and delimiters that I haven't found this information. I appreciate this and will probably start using braces from now on.

Comment: Actually, I imagine it might be more applicable to dynamic method names rather than properties... just an example though :)

Comment: @KDOT I'd actually suggest that you only use braces when you need to, otherwise it just adds unnecessary clutter to the code.

Comment: It look's so clean though hahahha #OCD @RobbieAverill

Comment: In that example it does, yeah - but for example `$e->{'my_var'}` seems excessive when compared to `$e->my_var`

Comment: You killed my vibe on using braces with that example ;) Thank's for the explanation and the resources though! @RobbieAverill