# How do I acces this property/element of this object/array?

Tags: php, arrays, stdclass

I'm trying to access a property of a stdClass but it's named after an index or something? I'm at a loss here, I would really appreciate some insight into how I can get at my data.
Thanks in advance,

```
 object(stdClass)#79 (96) {
 ["0"]=> <------this is what I'm trying to access
 array(1) {
   [0]=>
   object(stdClass)#80 (5) {
      ["m_id"]=>
      string(3) "422"
      ["klplan_id"]=>
      string(3) "945"
      ["m_naam"]=>
      string(62) "opsporen lekkage vanuit badkamer/kitten bad rand /parkeren/kit"
      ["m_aantal"]=>
      string(1) "1"
      ["m_prijs"]=>
      string(4) "7.25"
  }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606340/get-a-php-object-property-that-is-a-number

Comment: That easy huh, I'm so embarrassed ;)

Answer (score 1):

This should do it:

```
$class->{'0'}
```