# Accessing number object in php

Tags: php, arrays, object

I got an object's value in foreach loop which is a number

```
> array(12) { [0]=> object(stdClass)#34 (22) {
                    [201609]=> string(6) "130000"
                  } }
```

When I try to access `$query->201609` getting error

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected T_LNUMBER, expecting T_STRING or T_VARIABLE or '{' or '$'

I try to access by using `$query->{201609}` it gives me 0 value instead of 130000

How can I get that attribute?

This question is not duplicate. I've tried the other question's it doesn't help for me because it is in a loop.

Comment: It can be helpful; https://www.sitepoint.com/community/t/convert-object-to-array/2930

Comment: `echo $query->{0}->{201609}`

Comment: @AlivetoDie  gives me 0 value instead of 130000.

Comment: oK WHAT ABOUT `echo $query[0]->{201609}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This works in Php 7.2.4 (likely older versions as well):

```
$property = 201609;
var_dump($query->$property);
```

Tested like this:

```
$x = new stdClass();
$p = 123;
$x->$p = 456;
var_dump($x);
```

Output:

```
object(stdClass)#3 (1) {
  ["123"]=>
  int(456)
}
```

Assuming "$query" is an array, not the object in question:

```
$property = 201609;
var_dump($query[0]->$property);
```

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
$query->{'201609'}
```

Seems to be duplicate of [Get a PHP object property that is a number](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9606340/get-a-php-object-property-that-is-a-number)

Comment: I tried this it gives me 0 value instead of 130000. Which I was said in my question.